# Django hidden input field problems

Tags: django, modelform

I have following model form where I have to add a hidden field.

```
class AddEditGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id_sel_comp = forms.CharField(
        label='selected company',
        initial=0,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id': 'id_sel_comp'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'id_sel_comp')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddEditGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm'})

    def as_two_col_layout(self):
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row='<div class="form-group m-form__group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">%(label)s</label><div class="col-sm-9">%(field)s%(help_text)s</div></div>',
        error_row='%s',
        row_ender='',
        help_text_html=' <span class="m-form__help">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row=True)
```

The form displays only the hidden form field and the 'name' charfield is not displayed. When I mark the field 'id_sel_comp' as NOT hidden, all fields are displayed. What is wrong with this?
The form is rendered in the template with:

```
{{ form.as_two_col_layout }}
```

Comment: _When I mark the field 'id_sel_comp' as NOT hidden_  -- how are you marking it as not hidden?

Comment: Check html code, not page render.

Comment: @WillKeeling: when I remove widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id': 'id_sel_comp'}) both fields are shown correctly

Comment: @IvanStarostin: I have, indeed in the source code I only see the hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify your `row_ender` properly. You are currently setting it to '' which isn't correct to what your specified as `normal_row`. Your `row_ender` in your case is `</div></div>`. So your `as_two_col_layout` becomes,

```
def as_two_col_layout(self):
    return self._html_output(
        normal_row='<div class="form-group m-form__group row">'
                   '<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">%(label)s</label>'
                   '<div class="col-sm-9">%(field)s%(help_text)s</div></div>',
        error_row='%s',
        row_ender='</div></div>',
        help_text_html=' <span class="m-form__help">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row=True)
```

Hope this helps!